# How to recognize ansi color escape codes in Windows7 64 bit command terminal

Tags: windows, command-prompt, windows-7-x64, ansi-escape

I have tried Ansicon and I still cannot get ansi escape sequences to become recognized and interpreted in my CMD.EXE command prompt on Windows 7 64 bit. Has anyone been able to work this correctly and get a colorized console with this OS?

Comment: win7 32bit also has this problem.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same problem today, and found a workaround.

The commandline utility [Windows ANSI Color](https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/wac) detects ANSI color codes and sets the corresponding console color.

Example:

```
myapp.bat | wac
```

where wac is the Windows ANSI color utility

Answer (score 3):

[ANSICON](http://adoxa.altervista.org/ansicon/) ([source](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon)) seems to work fine for me...

- Put ansicon somewhere you intend to keep it...
- Run `ANSICON -I`
- Close the terminal
- Open a new one...

Answer (score 2):

Ansicon use dll injection in order to enable ansi color in cmd.exe, which is disabled with the standard user privileges.

Try launching ansicon with "run as administrator" (right click)

Answer (score -1):

I've played a lot with this, and the best console for me is FarManager on Windows. http://www.farmanager.com/

It's a file manager, but with CTRL+O you will get the console, and very handy with full support of ANSI, autocomplete, etc.