# ←[0m←[42m←[37mIf in the console output

Tags: c++11, output, header-files

This is the source.cpp

```
#include "color.hpp"
#include<conio.h>
int main()
{
    std::cout << std::endl
              << color::style::reset << color::bg::green << color::fg::gray
              << "If you're seeing green bg, then color works!"
              << color::style::reset << std::endl;
    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the code snippet from color.hpp :

```
template <typename T>
using enable = typename std::enable_if
    <
        std::is_same<T, color::style>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, color::fg>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, color::bg>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, color::fgB>::value ||
        std::is_same<T, color::bgB>::value,
        std::ostream &
    >::type;

template <typename T>
inline enable<T> operator<<(std::ostream &os, T const value)
{
    std::streambuf const *osbuf = os.rdbuf();
    return ((supportsColor()) && (isTerminal(osbuf)))
               ? os << "\033[" << static_cast<int>(value) << "m"
               : os;
}
}
```

Actually this is a header only library for making colorful console. I tried to compile this project as a console application with C++11 support but the output is unexpected. What do the output suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output suggests that `color.hpp` depends on a terminal which is interpreting special "escape" output code, but your terminal does not interpret these codes.

This isn't standard C++, BTW.

Comment: @dlpsankhla  C++ has no concept of what kind of terminal you have and how it might interpret your output.  An equivalent ananogy would be opening a spreadsheet file with a text editor.  You can see the data but the text editor doesn't interpret the data and display it as rows and columns.  You may be looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2294281/how-to-recognize-ansi-color-escape-codes-in-windows7-64-bit-command-terminal

Comment: @dlpsankhla  If you are using Windows 10 then there is built in support.  Check this one out as well: http://www.nivot.org/blog/post/2016/02/04/Windows-10-TH2-%28v1511%29-Console-Host-Enhancements